# animate not working-JQuery

Tags: jquery

Am I doing anything wrong that my simple animate does not work?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p83y6/2/)

```
$('#my_btn').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
  $("#my_txt").animate({left:'350px'});
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element must have a position other than the default `static` for `top` and `left` to have any effect

```
#my_txt {position: relative; }
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p83y6/3/)

Preferably it would have an initial left style set as well

```
#my_txt {
    position: relative; 
    left : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

left is for element in position absolute.
you can use marginLeft like this:

```
$('#my_btn').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
  $("#my_txt").animate({marginLeft:'350px'});
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p83y6/5/)

or set `position:absolute` to your span like this to use `left` in animate:

CSS

```
#my_txt{
    position:absolute;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#my_btn').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
  $("#my_txt").animate({left:'350px'});
});
```